# jQuery Hover Function On A Dynamically Added Class

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble adding an active class when hovering on a dynamically added element. I've simplified the code below. I have read about the .on functionality but can't get this to function either.

```
$('.mainMenu').addClass('film');

$('.mainMenu.film').hover(  
    function ($) {  
    $('li.film').addClass('active');  
},  
function ($) {  
    $('li.film').removeClass('active');   
}
);
```

The below .on solution is not doing anything:

```
$('.mainMenu').on({
mouseenter: function($) {
    $('li.film').addClass('active');
},
mouseleave: function($) {
    $('li.film').removeClass('active');
}
}, ".film");
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with the new on is, is that you should add it to the body listener.

So basically:

```
$("parentobject").on('click','.mainMenu', function() {
  Do your stuff
});
```

Or even better:

```
$("parentobject").on('.mainMenu', {
mouseenter: function($) {
    $('li.film').addClass('active');
},
mouseleave: function($) {
    $('li.film').removeClass('active');
}
}, ".film");
```

Not tested, but should point you in the right direction

Comment: Add the handler to a `parent` element instead of the `body` \ `document`. So jQuery has only a subset of handlers to check if the selector matches on the element which triggered the event. Otherwise it has to check all the registered handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working, when you add a new element, class is added:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mainmenu').on('mouseenter','.film', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('.mainmenu').on('mouseleave','.film', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

But I think you should use CSS if you use class only to style element:

```
li.film       {color:black} // Your normal style
li.film:hover {color:red  } // Your active style
```